# Can applicationset create application for every subfolder (recursively) that gets created in the source Git Repo?

Tags: continuous-integration, cicd, argocd, argo, gitops

My Source Git repo directory looks like this:

```
K8s-envs/
├── Dev
├── Int
├── Preprod
└── Prod
```

Currently I have 4 applications for each env (via List Generator) from the above setup.

Is it possible to applicationset to create new applications for the subfolders (recursively) that gets created within these folders?

Like:

```
K8s-envs/
├── Dev
│       ├── sub-folder1
│       ├── sub-folder2
│       └── sub-folder3
├── Int
│       ├── sub-folder1
│       ├── sub-folder2
│       └── sub-folder3
├── Preprod
│       ├── sub-folder1
│       ├── sub-folder2
│       └── sub-folder3
└── Prod
        ├── sub-folder1
        ├── sub-folder2
        └── sub-folder3
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I haven't tested it but git generator with a path `k8s-envs/*/*` should work. Then you can access parts of the path using `path[0]` for instance.

Comment: Ok, I will try the git generator and will see if it works or not. Will update the progress here.